# Convert string to date when the months are coded as m1,m2,m3,m4...,m12

Tags: r, date

I'm working on a panel dataset, but the date is written as "year + m + month number". For example:

```
"1999M1", "1999M2", "1999M3", "1999M4", "1999M5"
```

Which are equivalent to 1999-Jan, 1999-Feb, 1999-Mar and so on.

I want to convert them to date format.

Comment: LUTs (look-up tables) are the simplest way to go here. -- other than `lubridate` as in an answer

Answer (score 3):

We can paste on `-01` for the day-of-month and then specify an appropriate format in `as.Date()`:

```
x = c("1999M1", "1999M2", "1999M3", "1999M4", "1999M5")
as.Date(paste0(x, "-01"), format = "%YM%m-%d")
# [1] "1999-01-01" "1999-02-01" "1999-03-01" "1999-04-01" "1999-05-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
as.Date(sub("(.+)M(.+)", "\\1-\\2-01", x))

# [1] "1999-01-01" "1999-02-01" "1999-03-01" "1999-04-01" "1999-05-01"
```

Or using `lubridate` which is part of `tidyverse` as well, it supports this format, so we can simply do:

```
lubridate::ym(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> s <- c("1999M1", "1999M2", "1999M3", "1999M4", "1999M5")

> paste0(sub("M.*","",s),"-",month.abb[as.integer(sub("\\d+M", "", s))])
[1] "1999-Jan" "1999-Feb" "1999-Mar" "1999-Apr" "1999-May
```

or

```
> s <- c("1999M1", "1999M2", "1999M3", "1999M4", "1999M5")

> strftime(as.Date(paste0(s, "-01"), format = "%YM%m-%d"), "%Y-%b")
[1] "1999-Jan" "1999-Feb" "1999-Mar" "1999-Apr" "1999-May"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively please try

```r
dat <- data.frame(date=c("1999M1", "1999M2", "1999M3", "1999M4", "1999M5"))

library(tidyverse)

df <- dat %>% mutate(year=as.numeric(str_extract_all(date,'\\d+(?=\\M)')),
               month=as.numeric(str_extract_all(date,'(?<=\\M)\\d+')),
               newdate=lubridate::ymd(paste(year,month,1,sep = '-'))
               )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
    date year month    newdate
1 1999M1 1999     1 1999-01-01
2 1999M2 1999     2 1999-02-01
3 1999M3 1999     3 1999-03-01
4 1999M4 1999     4 1999-04-01
5 1999M5 1999     5 1999-05-01
```